# Superset picking Timestamp type of Trino tables as UNKNOWN

Tags: presto, apache-superset, trino

Trino (formerly known as Presto SQL) Version - 341
SuperSet Version - 0.37.2

I have a table in Trino that has 1250 columns. 118 of these columns are timestamp type. When I add this table under Sources -> Tables -> Add a new record, all these timestamps are being identified as UNKNOWN. However, when I manually edit each timestamp column and change UNKNOWN -> TIMESTAMP, it all works fine as expected. Can someone help mitigate this problem? Is this a bug?

Adding the DB table in the below screen
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Trino (formerly known as Presto) supports parametric timestamp types which the legacy clients couldn't understand. There was a flag added in Trino - 338 to support this. After I added the property as a session property value in Superset Trino connection, this got resolved.

More details:

```
https://github.com/trinodb/trino/pull/4349
https://github.com/trinodb/trino/pull/4377
https://trino.io/docs/current/release/release-338.html
```

user can either set below property in Presto config:

> deprecated.omit-datetime-type-precision: true

or using session property:

> omit_datetime_type_precision

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `datetime` type, use `timestamp`.